# Problems merging data frames in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames:

```r
x <- data.frame("coi" = c(0,1,NA,1),"v2" = c(7,8,9,NA))
y <- data.frame("c1" = c(0,-1,1), "c2" = c(0,-1,-1), "coi" = c(0,1,NA))
```

```
> x
  coi v2
1   0  7
2   1  8
3  NA  9
4   1 NA
> y
  c1 c2 coi
1  0  0   0
2 -1 -1   1
3  1 -1  NA
```

And I want to merge them into something like this:

```
> obj
  coi v2 c1 c2
1   0  7  0  0
2   1  8 -1 -1
3  NA  9  1 -1
4   1 NA -1 -1
```

but when i try

```
merge(x,y)
```

I'm getting this:

```
  coi v2 c1 c2
1   0  7  0  0
2   1  8 -1 -1
3   1 NA -1 -1
4  NA  9  1 -1
```

which is not bad, but is there anyway to preserve the original order in column "coi"?

Comment: Not using `merge`. According to the help page: "The rows are by default lexicographically sorted on the common columns, but for sort = FALSE are in an unspecified order. "

Comment: Right. Solved with a simple plyr::join(x,y)

Answer (score 5):

you can use something like:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(x, y, by = "coi")
```

you will get:

```
  coi v2 c1 c2
1   0  7  0  0
2   1  8 -1 -1
3  NA  9  1 -1
4   1 NA -1 -1
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case (match only one) you can use `cbind` in combination with `match` like:

```
cbind(x, y[match(x$coi, y$coi),-3])
#    coi v2 c1 c2
#1     0  7  0  0
#2     1  8 -1 -1
#3    NA  9  1 -1
#2.1   1 NA -1 -1
```

Comment: Nice way to use cbind and match.